# Is my proof for the fact that there are arbitrarily long strips of numbers between successive primes correct?

Tags: solution-verification, induction, integers, prime-gaps

My attempt at a proof by induction:

Let two successive primes be $a$ and $b$.
$a - b = c$ gives the number of numbers between them.

Base case: The first five values of $c$ are $0,1,1,3$ and $1$.
There is no pattern that indicates the next value of $c$ hence they are arbitrary.

Inductive step: Assume the values of $c$ are arbitrary for all $2 \le K \le P$ where $K$ and $P$ are primes.
Since, all the values of $C$ till $P$ are arbitrary, any value of $P - K$ will be
arbitrary relative to the previous $C$s

Hence all $C$s will be arbitrary.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: (1) the number of positive integers between a and b is $c-1$, not $c$. (2) In the base case, can you PROVE, definitively, that there IS no pattern? Doesn’t it seem a bit egotistical to suggest that just because *you* can’t see it, therefore it mustn’t exist? (3) you have completely misunderstood the meaning of “arbitrary” here. You took it to mean “unpredictable”. What it means here is “if you said a random number out loud, one could  find two primes with exactly that many numbers between them.”

Comment: K cool. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not correct. The term "arbitrarily" means that for any $n$, there is a prime gap of length $\geq n$. It doesn't mean that there is no pattern.

There are also some other problems. You didn't state your induction hypothesis. You also didn't prove anything in your base case. In the induction case, you use "arbitrary" as if it's a property of numbers when it isn't.